# Date in INT but it's not epoch time

Tags: sql-server, datetime, unix, epoch

I have '77337' and '4477877' delcared as INT in a client's database in SQL Server.
Their app displays the following date and time as 9/24/2012 and 12:26 respectively.
How were these computed?

From the database:

[image: from the database]

From the application:

[image: from the app]

I tried use epoch time or unix time, but it's a far match

Edited the screenshots for more examples

Comment: It helps to have more than a single example to work from for each, since you can then e.g. compare the differences between two dates and see if there are any units which then make sense, similarly for the times. With only a single example, someone may provide an answer which is correct for *this sample and this sample only* and, in fact, there are a multitude of possible wrong answers like that.

Comment: sorry about that, I reuploaded newer screenshots

Comment: A simple test with two statements `SELECT DATEADD(day, -77337, CONVERT(date, '20120924')); SELECT DATEADD(day, -77418, CONVERT(date, '20121214'))` returns `1800-12-28`, so the `int` values in the database are probably number of days after `1800-12-28`.

Comment: The days component is an offset from some date around 1800. Just use one if the dates and substract the respective number of days from it to get the base date. For the time, divide by 360000 and you will get the hours since 00:00

Comment: Please don't use images for data, use tabular formatted text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @zhorov in comments the entrydate values are number of days after `1800-12-28`, so the complete calcul can be :

```
select *, CONVERT(date, (DATEADD(day, entrydate, '1800-12-28'))) AS DATE,
          FLOOR(entrytime/3600/100) AS HOURS , 
          FLOOR(entrytime/3600%100*60/100) AS MINUTES
from mytable
```

Result :

| entrydate | entrytime | DATE | HOURS | MINUTES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 77337 | 4477877 | 2012-09-24 | 12 | 25 |
| 77418 | 3135704 | 2012-12-14 | 8 | 42 |

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/3UcKtby8)